# Bad perfomance of mass insertion to Redis DB with Sider .NET client

Tags: c#, database, nosql, redis

I need to insert about one million key-value pairs in **[Redis DB](http://redis.io)**. I have a Redis server instance on the same computer with my C# application. I use **[Sider](https://github.com/chakrit/sider)** client to connect to Redis. All settings are default. The following code executes for **4 seconds**:

```
    redis_client.Pipeline(c =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("\r" + i);
            string key = "aaaaaaaaaaa" + i;
            string value = "bbbbbbbbbb";
            c.Set(key, value);
        }
    });
```

I tried both usual and pipeline method of insertion. Standard benchmark of Redis shows similar results. CPU or HDD have no problems and them enough for another mass insertion in different databases. **[Official benchmark page](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)** of Redis says about possibility of ~100000 SET operations per second. I have less then 1000... What's the problem?

Comment: Answers here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/redis-db/pWNMmpYx928